# Pandas changing date to a shorter format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

G'day!

In my limited time working with Python and Pandas one question comes up time and time again - what if my input data has date/time in a long format, how to change it to a shorter version?

For example, the date in the input file would be:

```
10/10/2019 5:52:30 AM
```

If I want to perform date/time operations with it, I'll need to convert it to datetime:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

So now I have datetime objects in full long format. But what if I only need the day/month/year?

I could of course convert them back to strings and then to convert them back into datetime format.

```
df = df['date'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

It hurts my eyes to look at this... There should be a simpler way of doing this, right?

Comment: Hurts your eyes doesn't mean it's not working or isn't effective / simple. If you're worried about readability, just do `DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"` somewhere else in your code, and use that

Comment: I just thought it looks unreasonably complicated, not pythonic at all. But it works so it'll do for now I guess.

Comment: While you say it does not "look pythonic", you could argue the opposite as one of the "zen of Python" lines says: "Explicit is better than implicit". Which does sometimes end up causing a bit more verbose code.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess you're right. I just thought there might be a simpler way that I simply don't know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) functions can do the job:

```
#Generate the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                'month': [2, 3],
                'day': [4, 5],
                'hour': [2, 23]})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df)

#Floor and round datetime
df['Date'].dt.floor('d')
df['Date'].dt.round('d')
```

The output for `dt.floor` is:

```
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and for `dt.round`:

```
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-06
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```